# Windows 7 keeps highlighting a particular item in start menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Windows 7 highlights newly installed items in start menu. When I click/run the newly installed item from the start menu, windows removes the highlight. I am fine with this behavior.

But sometimes windows keeps highlighting the new item even after I click/run it for many times. And windows keeps highlighting it for DAYS! This is annoying.

I don't want to turn off highlighting completely. What is wrong with this particular item? How do I turn off highlight for this particular item?